# In a second countable space any base has a countable subset that is still a base

Tags: general-topology

If the topology of a space  has a countable base, then each base contains a countable subfamily which is also a base.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: this is the full question as written in my book! I use the theorem  that one set is base if and only if each member of the topology consist of the union of it's members.Then I consider the case that x belongs to some subset T of X and that T is the union of countable bases.After those thoughts I have problem to prove that the union of T's is equal to each member of X in order to prove the given statement=

Comment: The relevant part was "ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it." Thanks for including some of your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal{B}=\{B_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable base for $\mathcal{T}$. Also, let $\mathcal{V}=\{V_i:i\in I\}$ be an other base for $\mathcal{T}$, where $I$ is an index set. We will first use the following "lemma":

**Lemma:** For every $G=\bigcup_{j\in J}V_j$ there is a countable subset $M$ of $J$, such that:
$$G=\bigcup_{j\in M}V_j$$

*Proof:* Let
$$\mathcal{U}=\{B\in\mathcal{B}:\mbox{there is $j\in J$ such that $B\subseteq V_j$}\}$$
Then, it is clear that 
$$\bigcup\mathcal{U}\subseteq G$$
For the inverse, we note that for every $x\in G$, there is a $j\in J$ such that $x\in V_j$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base, there is a $B\in \mathcal{B}$, such that $x\in B\subseteq V_i$, so $B\in\mathcal{U}$. Therefore:
$$G\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{U}$$
So, for every $B\in\mathcal{U}$, we choose a $j_B\in J$, such that $B\subseteq V_{j_B}$ and $M=\{j_B:B\in\mathcal{U}\}$. Then 
$$\bigcup\mathcal{U}\subseteq\bigcup_{j\in M} V_{j}\subseteq G$$
so 
$$G=\bigcup_{j\in M}V_j$$

Back to our question, for every set $B_n\in\mathcal{B}$, since $\mathcal{V}$ is a base, we can write:
$$B_n=\bigcup_{j\in J}V_{n,j}$$
for some $J\subseteq I$. Due to the previous Lemma, we can find a countable collection of the abovementioned $V_{n,j}$ such that:
$$B_n=\bigcup_{j\in M}V_{n,j}$$
So, let 
$$\mathcal{V}'=\left\{V_{n,j}:B_n=\bigcup_{j\in M}V_{n,j}\mbox{ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\right\}$$
It is obvious that $\mathcal{V}'$ is countable and that it is a base for $\mathcal{T}$, since every element of $\mathcal{B}$ can be written as a union of sets of $\mathcal{V}'$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Proof of lemma: $X$ is heriditarily Lindelöf. (If one happens to know about such things)

Comment: Accidentally, I was reading recently about Lindeloef spaces, but I thought I should avoid any reference to it, since I do not feel that comfortable with them either... :P

Comment: I don't think you need $J$. You could say for every $G\in\mathcal T$ there is a countable $M_G\subseteq I$, etc.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing special about the countable case, it works for all infinite cardinalities. Proof follows Engelking, General Topology.

**Theorem** Let $X$ be a space and suppose $X$ has a base $\mathcal{M}$ of size $\kappa$, some infinite cardinal.
If $\mathscr{B}$ is any base for the topology of $X$, then there exists a subfamily $\mathscr{B}' \subseteq \mathscr{B}$ such that $\left|\mathscr{B}'\right| \le \kappa$ and $\mathscr{B}'$ is still a base for the space $X$.

So for example, if $X$ has a countable base, all other bases of $X$ can be "thinned out" to a countable base, by possibly throwing some sets away.

**Proof**:

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be any base for $X$.

Then define $$I = \{(M_1, M_2) \in \mathscr{M} \times \mathscr{M}: \exists B \in \mathscr{B}: M_1 \subseteq B \subseteq M_2 \}$$

Note that $\left|I\right| \le \kappa^2 = \kappa$, and we apply the Axiom of Choice to pick for each $i \in I$ (where $i = (M^i_1, M^i_2)$), some $B_i \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $M^i_1 \subseteq B_i \subseteq M^i_2$.

We claim that $\mathscr{B}' := \{B_i: i \in I\} \subseteq \mathscr{B}$ is also a base for $X$, and clearly $\left| \mathscr{B'}\right| \le |I| \le \kappa$ and so we would be finished.

To see it is a base: let $O$ be open in $X$ and $x \in O$. We have to find some $B_i$ that sits between them.

First use that $\mathscr{M}$ is a base and find $M_2 \in \mathscr{M}$ such that

$$x \in M_2 \subseteq O$$

Then use that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base (applied to $x$ and $M_2$) and find $B \in \mathscr{B}$ such that

$$ x \in B \subseteq M_2 \subseteq O$$

Again apply that $\mathscr{M}$ is a base (to $x$ and $B$) and find $M_1 \in \mathscr{M}$ such that

$$ x \in M_1 \subseteq B \subseteq M_2 \subseteq O$$

Aha! We have that $i:= (M_1, M_2) \in I$ (we've forced it that way using the base property ) So we have already picked some $B_i = B_{(M_1, M_2)}\in \mathscr{B}'$  (it's probably some other member, not necessarily our $B$ from above), such  that

$$ x \in M_1 =M^i_1 \subseteq B_i \subseteq M^i_2 = M_2 \subseteq O$$

And we have found the required member of $\mathscr{B}'$ between $x$ and $O$.
This finishes the proof.

(footnote: a "modern proof" would pick an elementary submodel of a sufficiently large fragment of ZFC of size $\kappa$, a bit of overkill for this case.)

Comment: Hi. I see there is an implicit assumption that $\mathcal B$ generates the same topology as $\mathcal M$? Am I correct?