# If X be a second countable space and N a base for the topology of X . Show that there is a countable base B for the topology of X such that B ⊂ N.

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove that if X be a second countable space and N a base for the topology of X then there is a countable base B for the topology of X such that B ⊂ N.

Comment: Let $\mathcal C$ be any countable basis. For each $C_1,C_2\in\mathcal C$, let $N(C_1,C_2)$ be an element of the basis $\mathcal N$ such that $C_1\subseteq N(C_1,C_2)\subseteq C_2$, if such an element exists, and let $N(C_1,C_2)=\varnothing$, if there is no such element. Try to see if you could do something with this idea.

Comment: @Mirko, just take an elementary submodel $\mathscr{M}$ of a large enough part of a model of ZFC that contains $X$, $N$ and look at the sets of $N$ that lie in $\mathscr{M}$.... (see Dow's papers on elementary submodels applied to topology)..

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2348694/4280) I give a complete proof for any cardinality.

Comment: @Mirko I did show only that $|\mathcal{B}'| \le \kappa$ and no more, I have adapted the claim to say that too, now. I'd love to do the Dow proof with elementary submodels, but I'm afraid the target audience for this site (most of them) would miss all the fun of it and consider it "dark magic", because of lack in background. I studied axiomatic set-theory and logic too, but the students struggling with Munkres probably have not...